# Image to Text Progam

Tags: c#

I have only one button which is supposed to do the thing but when I press it nothing happens? I know it's just a small mistake which I just can't see right now may be somebody can help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private string ConvertImage(Bitmap sBit)
    {
        MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        sBit.Save(imageStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(imageStream.ToArray());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap sBit = new Bitmap(@"C:\12.jpg");
        string imageString = ConvertImage(sBit);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\12.text", false);
        sw.Write(imageString);
        sw.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is impossible that nothing happens. The code either runs or throws an exception. Did you bind the event handler?

Comment: Inspect that "button1" control: did you bind it's Click event to your handler?

Comment: go to `InitializeComponent()` definition (click on it and press F12) and look if you have this line: `this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);`. If you don't, put it :)

Comment: It ran but when I clicked the button nothing happened. I forgot to bind the button to the click event. Can't believe I missed that :(

Answer (score 2):

Did you bind the button to a click event?

[image]

The InitializeComponent method should contain this line:

this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

Comment: Is there a reason for downvote?

Comment: Thanks a lot.I completely forgot about it. Still it doesn't convert the image to text, just creates a text file with random characters in it. Looks like i messed something up. Thank you any way for help!!

Comment: What characters would you expect in the file?

Comment: I expect the characters from the Jpeg image. It's just an image which says "Hello".I want it to work like an OCR.

Comment: :D. Then you should use an ocr lib. It is not that easy as you want it to be :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint.